OE11.7 to OE12.8 - Field name was not found on table
After migrating from Progress 11.7 to Progress 12.8, I started having some problems while opening some .W files on App Builder.
This only occurs to a few programs, in multiple databases, with different fields and tables.
I'm having this issue:
FIELD name WAS NOT FOUND IN TABLE table. ABORTING OPENING OF FILE.
If I try to open again, the error repeats for another field and keeps looping between them.
(Some programs I have this issue too, but when I try to open for the second time, it opens normally)
The field is just normal on database, I've been able to compile the program using App Compiler, it's just not possible to open using App Builder.
​Other programs that uses this field, works normally too.
Did anyone have this error? Or managed to fix it?

According to this article, it occurs when you try to open a .w file containing a browse accessing a table from the second connected database in the AppBuilder.
It should be fixed in OpenEdge 12.8.5.
As a workaround, you could also change the order of database connections, but it might just move the problem to another .w file.
